# Check for existing node titles

Tags: ajax

Is there a way to Add autocomplete to Node Titles?

This way I could display duplicate content to users before they add a new post.

Any suggestions?

Comment: [This question](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/7322/adding-autocomplete-to-title-field-of-node-form) has an incomplete answer in the question itself. Looks like that user was able to get autocomplete working for node titles based on existing node titles, but got stuck getting it to work for users that don't have the Administer Nodes permission. Should be a good starting point at least.

Comment: What data is being pulled by autocomplete to fill the title?

Comment: I dont have autocomplete, since this is content type i dont even know how i would add autocomplete manually. :(

Answer (score 0):

Used Finder module as separate input box for people to check for existing titles.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [Uniqueness Module](https://drupal.org/project/uniqueness)

> Uniqueness module provides a way to avoid duplicate content on your
>   site by informing a user about similar or related content during
>   creation of a new post